# What's the benefit of manually adding / removing event handlers, instead of assigning them through the UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, .net-3.5

At work, my old boss would insist we programmatically assign and remove event handlers from our controls in the code behind, rather than simply double clicking a button (for example).

We'd have an `AttachEvents()` and `DetachEvents()` method on every single form. I don't remember his explanation as to why this is allegedly better than assigning it from the Design View, and he's since been transferred to a different project. My new manager doesn't know.

I *thought* he said it had something to do with events not properly being removed from memory, but I really don't know.

So: What is the benefit of doing it this way?

Comment: because you will have better control on attaching and detaching event handlers and yes some times you may need to detach an event handlers from runtime.that's why it is good to know how to attach/detach event handlers from coding rather from designer

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise they are the same.
But doing it in the code behind is a much neater way since you control when to `AttachEvents()` or `DetachEvents()`

But you have to be careful in terms of avoiding any duplicate event wire ups. These in turn might lead up eating memory, but prominently they would cause performance issues since the event handler would be called as many times as it was wired up.

Answer (score 0):

Some event handlers such as timers need to be removed before leaving a form otherwise they would still fire, for example
timer.Elapsed += ...
and
timer.Elapse -= ...
Probably a good and clear way to remember to do it in this way.

Comment: Here you should stop the timer, not removing the timer but leave it firing.  That's leaking a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the implications of your own architecture, there's no difference whatsoever.

The designer will place the event subscriptions on the `InitializeComponent` method and you should not do any changes to that method because the designer might override them or crash if it's something it can't handle.

Usually, the event subscriptions are events the form subscribes from its children. When the from is closed/disposed, all the children are disposed and each child will dispose event subscriptions.

Problems arise when the form subscribes to outside components. Then the form becomes "attached" to those components and, if not unsubscribed, becomes a resource leak.

There's also the possibility of events being fired when the form is not ready to handle them.

I've used a mixed approach where events from child controls were subscribed in the designer (or carefully manually coded in the `InitializeComponent` method) and used the `AttachEvents`/`DetachEvents` approach for components outside the UI (or the scope of the form/control).